# Python Twitter bot works from interpreter but not when run as program?

Tags: python, twitter

**answered**

I've written a toy program to emulate a particular Twitter user (scraped their tweets, ran them through NLTK, wrote a generator, etc). Everything works with the program and I can print to terminal just fine.

Now, I'm trying to hook it up to Twitter. I'm using Python Twitter Tools (http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/#screenshots). At the beginning I have one of these with my info:

```
t = Twitter(
            auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
                       CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
           )
```

And at the end I have one of these:

```
tweet = choice (possTweets)
t.statuses.update(status=tweet)
```

Now, here's the odd bit. If I run my program through the interpreter (meaning I enter python and type in the code manually) like so:

```
>>> import twitter
>>> from twitter import *
>>> t = Twitter(
            auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
                       CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
           )
>>> t.statuses.update(status="test")
```

it works fine, and updates the Twitter account. If, however, I run myProgram.py in the terminal, I get this:

```
File "myProgram.py", line 148, in <module>
t.statuses.update(status="test2")
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'statuses'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: print out `t` right before the line that throws your error.

Comment: Aha, that did it! I was using t to iterate elsewhere in the program. Swiched the t.statuses to tw.statuses and it works!

Comment: Okay, that question won't help anybody else.

Answer (score 2):

Blender helped me figure it out - I was using t elsewhere in the program to iterate through the list, and once I switched to tw.statuses it worked fine!